# Rewrite the following in symbolic forms using $\sim, \land, \lor $.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $h = $"Peter is handsome", $c = $"Peter is clever", $o = $"Peter is optimistic". Rewrite the following in symbolic forms using $ \sim , \land, \lor $.

-Peter is neither handsome, clever nor optimistic.

answer: $\sim(h \lor c \lor o)$

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is correct.

I think of the claim "Peter is neither handsome, clever nor optimistic" as "Peter is not handsome, and he is not clever, and he is not optimistic", which you can write as
$$(\sim h)\land (\sim c)\land (\sim o).$$
By DeMorgan's law, this is equivalent to your answer of
$$\sim (h\lor c\lor o).$$